# Hooks and immutable state

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am apologising in advance if this questions has already been answered before *(and also for the long post, but I've tried to be as specific as I could be)*. But, the answers I found does not completely satisfy me.

I want to use the new amazing React Hooks for my project. And for what I've been doing so far, it has been straight forward.

Now I have ran into a more complex example, and I feel unsure on how I best should tackle this one.

Let's say, I have more of a complex object *(at least it's not flat)* in my state.

```
{
    persons: [
        {
            id: 1,
            name: 'Joe Doe',
            age: 35,
            country: 'Spain',
            interests: [
                { id: 1, en: 'Football', es: 'Fútbol' },
                { id: 2, en: 'Travelling', es: 'Viajar' }
            ]
        },
        {
            id: 2,
            name: 'Foo Bar',
            age: 28,
            country: 'Spain',
            interests: [
                { id: 3, en: 'Computers', es: 'Computadoras' },
                { id: 4, en: 'Cooking', es: 'Cocinar' }
            ]
        }
    ],
    amount: 2,
    foo: 'bar'
}
```

What is the best way to:

1. Add an item (an object) to my colleagues array
2. Add an item to a specific "interests" array?
3. Manipulate the value of a property within an object in the array?
4. Change a value outside the persons array, for example `foo`?

using the useState hook?

The following code examples will try to illustrate each question. They're not tested...

Let us consider I have a container that begins with this.
It also includes the functions that are split up in the rest of the post.

```
const [colleagues, setColleagues] = useState({});

// using the useEffect as "componentDidMount
useEffect(() => {

    // receiving data from ajax request
    // and set the state as the example object provided earlier
    setColleagues(response.data);
}, []);
```

**1)** So for the first question. Is this valid?
Or do I need to to make sure that each and every object in my `persons array` is destructured?

```
const onAddNewColleague = () => {

    // new colleague, this data would be dynamic
    // but for the sake of this example I'll just hard code it
    const newColleague = {
        name: 'Foo Baz Bar',
        age: 30,
        country: 'Spain',
        interests: [
            { en: 'Cats', es: 'Gatos' }
        ]
    };

    // creates a copy of the state
    // targets the "persons" prop and adds a new array
    // where the new colleague is appended
    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        persons: colleagues.concat(newColleague)

    };

    // updates the state
    setColleagues(newState);
};
```

**2)** This feels wrong as I end up updating the entire `persons array` instead of just the `interest array` for a specific person.

```
const onAddNewInterest = (personId) => {
    // a new interest
    const newInterest = {
        en: 'Languages', es: 'Idiomas'
    };

    // find the person according to personId
    // and update the interests
    const updatedPersons = colleagues.persons.map(person => {
        if(person.id === personId) {
            return {
                ...person,
                interests: person.interests.concat(newInterest);
            };
        }

        return person;
    });

    // create a copy of the state
    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        persons: [...updatedPersons]
    };

    setColleagues(newState);
};
```

**3)** As the second example, this one feels wrong too as I am updated the entire `persons array` when in fact I might just want to change the `age` of one specific person

```
const onChangeValue = (personId, key, value) => {

    // find the person
    const updatedPersons = colleagues.persons.map(person => {

        if(person.id === personId) {
            // key, could be age?
            return {
                ...person,
                [key]: value
            };
        }

        return person;
    });

    // create a copy of the state
    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        persons: [...updatedPersons]
    };

    setColleagues(newState);
};
```

**4)** Is this valid, or do I need to destruct every part of my `colleagues object` separately?

```
const onChangeOtherValue = (key, value) => {
    // for example changing the value foo

    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        [key]: value
    };

    setColleagues(newState);
};
```

I do have a feeling that only the concept of the first function is valid, while the rest of them are not.

Can this be done easily, or should I just use an immutable-helper?

Thanks in advance!

**Updated examples to get syntax, right. Thanks Valerii.**

**To clarify**
What I'm really after here is best practise to handle use cases like this one. I want to make sure my state is updated in the most correct and efficient way. So feel free to rip my examples a part or write new ones - I'm all ears. It is not necessary to simply modify mine to fit this post (unless they actually turn out to be good).

Comment: Have you looked into using the `useReducer` hook? It'll make more complex state transition simpler, as you can provide a more comprehensive set of transitions, and move the logic outside the component

Comment: Hey! I have looked into useReducer and that's a cool hook too! But I still need to make sure my state is updated in an immutable way, right? It's this nested state that I feel uncertain about.. Feel free to add an example :)

Comment: What you want is probably called "structural sharing" - reuse as much as possible and only copy over what's necessary.

Answer (score 1):

1) OK

2)

```
    const updatedPersons = colleagues.persons.map(person => {
        if(person.id === personId) {
            return {
                ...person,
                interests: person.interests.concat({ en: 'Test', es: 'Test' })
            };
        }

        return person;
    });

    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        persons: updatedPersons
    };
```

3)

```
    const updatedPersons = colleagues.persons.map(person => {

        if(person.id === personId) {
            return {
                ...person,
                [key]: value
            };
        }

        return person;
    });

    // create a copy of the state
    const newState = {
        ...colleagues,
        persons: updatedPersons
    };
```

4) OK

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I added one more example to my post. The approaches you provided for example 2 and 3 makes me update the entire `persons array`, even though the changes only applies to a specific person. Is this the way to go? Or is there a better way? As the other `persons` are not being manipulated, I guess they're not mutated and those objects does not need to be applied as a new object. Or should I in fact `return { ...person}` to make sure or does that make no sense?

Comment: @entiendoNull, You don't update array. When map is used new array is created. Important point is you don't need to create whole new sate, you need to create new instances only for objects you are going to update.

Answer (score 0):

for the first one, i would do this way,

```
    const newState = {
          ...colleagues,
          persons: [...persons, newColleague]

    };
```